# Call from App Extension (iMessage)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-app-extension, ios10, xcode8

I'm working on iMessage app extension for my app and i was wondering if its possible to initiate a phone call from App Extension?

I tried using the following code but it takes me (deeplink) to containing app.

```
cell.didTapCallNowButton = { cell in
    if let phoneNumber = cell.Model.phone,
        let url = URL(string: "telprompt:\(phone)") {
        self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from pdm 'Apple Staff' on Apple developer forum:

**No. iMessage apps can only open URLs in their parent app.**

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/174112#174112